# In Galaxy S3 call history, does the orange arrow mean incoming or outgoing call?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, call-history

Though this is may sound very trivial, this is not a troll question. I do not own an android phone and need to know for something.

Comment: I own a S2 but I assume the icons are the same; orange arrow pointing right is call you made so outgoing, green arrow pointing left is incoming call. Missed call is an arrow bouncing off (e.g. like [this](http://behance.vo.llnwd.net/profiles3/198840/projects/3234165/e3b420f87b09d2c4857d43f93e664ccb.png))

Answer (score 2):

Orange right pointing arrow is outgoing.
Green left pointing is incoming received.